# Why is the code not reaching else part

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

In this servlet,the code is never reaching the else part why so?even though i have not added any cookies and it is still printing some random value?Why so?

```
public class profile extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        Cookie[] ck=req.getCookies();

        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=resp.getWriter();
        if(ck!=null)
        {
            System.out.println("hello");
            RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
            rd.include(req, resp);
            out.println("welcome to your profile "+ck[0].getValue());
        }   
        else
        {
            out.println("sorry annonymous,you have to login first");
            RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
            rd.include(req, resp);
        }

    }

}
```

and even eclipse was saying dead code why so?

Comment: Well if it's non-null, you can presumably look at what cookies it *does* have... What exactly do you mean by "some random value"?

Comment: The session cookie is probably that "random value".

Comment: @JonSkeet like this welcome to your profile 2CDEC5DB0EEFFB7DAEAEC71D242AD2D6

Comment: have you check your ck variable value in debug mode?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin but i haven't added one,is something wrong with my code?

Comment: @TusharShimpi no i haven't

Comment: @user3590092 Your server might add a cookie, to keep track of the current session.

Comment: @A.Agarwal and how to stop that from happening?

Comment: You don't want to stop that from happening, you want to properly design your code to not make any assumptions. You don't want to check if there is "a" cookie, you want to check if a specific cookie exists.

Comment: The correct way to validate if a user is logged in or not would be to use session, you set some value in session and then you get it, and check on this value if user is valid/logged in user.

Comment: @Gimby when i tried to see what actually it is displaying,buy using getName method it printed jsessionid

Answer (score 1):

Instead of verifying existance of cookies.
You should verify some exact value, that you can prevously set with setCookies method.